# Change variable inside service for testing with PHPUnit inside Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I created a thread about Testing Services with phpunit inside symfony. Now that I figured it out, I have the following problem. I have this service, which get’s User Cart by ID.

```
class CartService
{

    private CartRepository     $cartRepository;
    private ManagerRegistry    $managerRegistry;
    private CartItemRepository $cartItemRepository;
    private Security           $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security, CartItemRepository $cartItemRepository, CartRepository $cartRepository, ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry)
    {
        $this->cartItemRepository = $cartItemRepository;
        $this->cartRepository = $cartRepository;
        $this->managerRegistry = $managerRegistry;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    /**
     * Get Cart by ID
     *
     * @return Cart|null
     */
    public function getCartByUserId(): ?Cart
    {
        $user = $this->security->getUser();
        return $this->cartRepository->findOneBy(['customer' => $user]);
    }
```

Since I am not logged in, I want to test this method with custom `$user`  ID. I tried to add integer to `$user`  variable inside CartServiceTest.php, but I get NULL as result.

```
class CartServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public CartService $cartService;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $container = static::getContainer();
        $this->cartService = $container->get(CartService::class);
    }

    public function testShowCart()
    {
        $user = 11; // Here 
        $cart = $this->cartService->getCartByUserId();
        dump($cart);

    }

}
```

Result:

```
PHPUnit 9.5.21 #StandWithUkraine

Testing App\Tests\CartServiceTest
^ null
R
```

As soon as I change my CartService, and add $user as argument, works, and I get Cart Object back.

```
/**
 * Get Cart by ID
 *
 * @return Cart|null
 */
public function getCartByUserId($user): ?Cart
{
    return $this->cartRepository->findOneBy(['customer' => $user]);
}
```

How can I change $user value inside unit testing? So I can run test with different user id’s?

Comment: Can't you mock a `Security` object which will return a valid user id when it's `getUser()` method is called? It is the `Cart` class you would like to the and not the `Security` class. Read more about mocking here: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

But what you can do, is to mock the `Security` service and make it return the `$user` object of your choice. For that, your `Security` service must be public.

```php
$myUser = ...;//here comes whatever you expect as a user value
$myMock = $this->createMock(Security::class);
$myMock->method('getUser')
  ->willReturn($myUser);

$container = static::getContainer();
$container->set(Security::class, $myMock)
```

Now you should be able to test your service.